# how to assign variable value with condition

Tags: python, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

I am work with python. I have code like this :

```
def return_auth_notificatio():
    shiporderid = all_Orderid
    cursor.execute("select *from return_auth_notification")
    email_record = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in email_record:
        Orderid = row[1]
        Customercomment =row[4]
        Amountreturn =row[5]
        condition_return_auth_notificatio=(Customercomment,Amountreturn if shiporderid == Orderid else None)
        assign_return_auth_notificatio=(condition_return_auth_notificatio if !Null )
    return(assign_return_auth_notificatio)

data=return_auth_notificatio()
all_Customercomment=data[0]
all_Amountreurn=data[1]
```

I want this  variable `Customercomment,Amountreturn` if records whose Orderid matches all_Orderid

Comment: Why don't you put the condition in the SQL query?

Comment: What is `!Null` supposed to mean? Python use `not` and `None`.

Comment: What if there's more than one record that matches `all_Orderid`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the condition in the query instead of the loop.

```
def return_auth_notificatio():
    customer_comments = []
    amount_returns = []
    cursor.execute("""
        select Customercomment, Amountreturn 
        from return_auth_notification 
        WHERE Orderid = %s""", (all_Orderid,))
    for comment, amount in cursor.fetchall():
        customer_comments.append(comment)
        amount_returns.append(amount)
    return customer_comments, amount_returns

all_Customercomment, all_Amountreturn = return_auth_notificatio()
```

The placeholder `%s` assumes you're using MySQL. If it's SQLite use `?` instead.

Comment: What's the benefit to using `%s` or `?` instead of an `f` string or something?

Comment: It prevents SQL-injection and avoids problems with characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL but %s is work on it.  What is the reason of using fetchone() method for fetching.

Comment: You're only returning one row from the function, so why fetch all the rows if you don't need them?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Are you expecting to return more than one row? The code in your question overwrites the variables each time through the loop, it doesn't create a list of results, so it just returns the last row.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get all the results, not just one row.

Comment: **"s-para-MQuantity"**  or **"ghera XXL"** I want to extract both words. It's written after **"SKU: "** word and I tried with this code **'SKU: ([\w[ -]]+)'** both words have deferent things in full string like **blank-space(" ") or dash("-")** , how to extract it?

Comment: You don't use nested brackets in regexp. `[\w[ -]]` should be `[-\w ]`